# using objects of two or more data types as key for c++ map, OOP

Tags: c++, oop

I have a `class` that contains a `map`. Earlier, there were two `maps`, one with `char` key and one with `string` key. I created a `class` that contains `enum` and `union` and two constructors, one from `char` and one from `string`, overloaded comparison operator and used that `class` as key.

But I keep wondering. could this have been solved with clever use of inheritance instead?

**edit:**

My class is something along the lines:

```
class A
{
    enum B
    {
        Ax, Ay
    } b;
    union C
    {
        X x;
        Y y;
    } c;
 public:
    A(X x) : b(Ax), c(x) {}
    A(Y y) : b(Ay), c(y) {}
    bool operator<(A& rhs)
    {
        if(this->b == rhs.b)
        {
            if(this->b == Ax) return this->c.x < b.c.x;
            if(this->b == Ay) reutrn this->c.y < b.c.y;
        }
        // if the "type" is different, I assume values are different
        // and all I need is any strong ordering, actual order doesn't matter
        return this->b < rhs.b;
    }
};
```

Later on I can use it fe. like that:

```
class Q
{
    // ...
public:
    Q(vector<A> v)
    {
        // don't worry about this code, I haven't figured out how c++11 for each
        // works exactly yet, but it's not important, I can do that myself
        for each (auto a in v)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
};
```

Now using curly brackets I can initialize `Q` with various `A`, and I can create distinct `A` from `char` or `string`.

My class, `A`accomplished this by containing union for the actual data required to compare keys of one type, and enum used to compare keys of different types. Basic inheritance tree with virtual base class and two subclasses would result in every instance containing the same amount of information - different internal variables would take role of the union, and different actual classes would take the role of the enum. But I just can't come up with a way to do it properly without breaking any important principles.

Comment: Can you show your currrent code? (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Take a [tour], read [mcve]

Comment: "When asking a question about a problem caused by your code," You do realize that I have no problem caused by my code? This is a completely different type of question.

Thanks for the downvote though.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `boost::variant` or [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) once the latter becomes available in your compiler?

It feels like the most natural solution to the problem and makes the code very readable:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using Key = boost::variant<char, std::string>;
    using Value = int; // whatever
    std::map<Key, Value> map;
    map['A'] = 1;
    map["B"] = 2;
    map["A"] = 3;

    for (auto&& key_value : map)
    {
        std::cout << key_value.first << " => " << key_value.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A => 1
A => 3
B => 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Although generally you can simplify `union` code with inheritance, it does not help much when you need mixed group of objects to have behavior that is aware of all other implementations.

You can make a base class, and have two subclasses - for string-based keys and for char-based keys. However, the comparison operator of string-based keys must know how to work with char-based keys, and the operator for char-based keys must know how to work with string-based keys. In situations like that the code becomes "monolithic", making a single class alternative more preferable.

In your situation, a class that exposes two constructors, and maintains a `string` internally should be an easy alternative:

```
class MyKey {
    string key;
    int subtype;
public:
    MyKey(const string& s) : key(s), subtype(1) {}
    MyKey(char c) : key(1, c), subtype(2) {}
    bool operator<(MyKey& other) {
        return subtype==other.subtype
             ? (key < other.key)
             : (subtype < other.subtype);
    }
};
```

Comment: This will result in 'a' being indistinguishable from "a" which was not my intention.

Comment: Yup, still it's more or less what I did, just You rely on the nature of char to avoid unions. But You're probably right that it can't be reasonably done with inheritance... I thought so even before asking, but wanted to try nevertheless.

Comment: @szpanczyk Right, the problem is in that last line of your code `return this->b < rhs->b` (which is also the last line of my code, for the same reason). Inheritance-based solution is good when any subclass can be coded up in isolation from all other classes, which is not possible in this case.