# Why is a Loop Giving Different Results Than accumulate?

Tags: c++, for-loop, lambda, accumulate

I've posted an answer here implementing Kahan's Summation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41743731/2642059 I used a lambda in `accumulate`:

```
accumulate(next(cbegin(small)), cend(small), big, [c = 0.0](const auto& sum, const auto& input) mutable {
    const auto y = input - c;
    const auto t = sum + y;

    c = t - sum - y;
    return t;
} )
```

This should have identical results to the `for`-loop:

```
auto sum = big;
auto c = 0.0;

for (long i = 0; i < size(small); ++i) {
    const auto y = small[i] - c;
    const auto t = sum + y;

    c = t - sum - y;
    sum = t;
}
```

But it does not. Given `vector<double> small(10000000, 1e-7)` `accumulate` yields:

> 1.999999900000000e+00

While the `for`-loop yields:

> 2.000000000000000e+00

Live Example at `http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cb0e3c542303eb4`

What's going on here? These 2 should evaluate to *exactly* the same code!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the accumulate example, you are not iterating over the entire set of values. `next(cbegin(small))` will begin at the element *after* `cbegin(small)`. Try this instead.

```
accumulate(cbegin(small), cend(small), big, /*the lambda*/);
```

Comment: Ugh, I left it in there from when I was seeding with `small.front()` rather than `big`. Thanks for doing the idiot test for me.